# preg_replace returns wrong line break?

Tags: php, preg-replace, line-breaks

Got a problem with preg_replace in a textarea. "$" or the "m" modifier are not working properly here:

```
<?php

$text = '1 - 2 - 3
a - b - c
foo - bar - baz';

$text_replaced = preg_replace('/^(.*) - (.*) - (.*)$/m', '$1 - $2 "$3"', $text); 

echo '
​<textarea rows=20 cols=20>
'.$text_replaced.'
</textarea>​​​​​​​​
';
```

should return

```
1 - 2 "3"
a - b "c"
foo - bar "baz"
```

but it returns

```
1 - 2 "3
"
a - b "c
"
foo - bar "baz"
```

How can this be solved?

Try yourself: http://codepad.viper-7.com/LqgDHg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `.` matches everything apart from `\n` (LF). You however use Windows style `\r\n` (CRLF) line breaks. Thus `\r` is included in the match.

What you probably want is this:

```
preg_replace('/(*ANYCRLF)^(.*) - (.*) - (.*)$/m', '$1 - $2 "$3"', $text);
```

The `(*ANYCRLF)` modifier changes the meaning of `.` towards accepting all characters apart from `\r` and `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text_replaced = preg_replace('/^(.*) - (.*) - (.*)[' . PHP_EOL . ']$/m', '$1 - $2 "$3"', $text);
```